# Pivot SQL query is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I need to create a `pivot` query to get some annual report with each week as column, the query is not working. During the troubleshooting, I've isolated it to the following:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
select [ProjectWork Number], WeekNO, WeekValue From dbo.staging 
) 

select [ProjectWork Number], WeekValue, 'Apr-03-2016', 'Apr-10-2016'
From PivotData
PIVOT
(
Sum(WeekValue) For WeekNO in ('Apr-03-2016', 'Apr-10-2016')
) As PivotResult
```

It throws error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near
>   'Apr-03-2016'.

More detailed discussion can be found on [sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1837710-3077-1.aspx)

It would be greatly appreciated if you can help me to sort it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ´Tag the dbms you're using! (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want square braces as delimiters, not single quotes.  The "dates" are column names, not vaues:

```
WITH PivotData AS (
    select [ProjectWork Number], WeekNO, WeekValue From dbo.staging 
) 
select [ProjectWork Number], WeekValue, [Apr-03-2016], [Apr-10-2016]
From PivotData
PIVOT (
    Sum(WeekValue) For WeekNO in ([Apr-03-2016], [Apr-10-2016])
) As PivotResult;
```

I would suggest that you use ISO standard date formats (such as YYYY-MM-DD), rather than location-dependent ones.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it fails "Invalid Column Name: WeekValue",  WeekValue is a column in dbo.staging, What does it mean?

Comment: @PasLeChoix . . . If `WeekValue` is indeed in `dbo.staging`, then I don't see how you could be getting that error.  Perhaps the name has a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH PivotData AS (select [ProjectWork Number], WeekNO, WeekValue From dbo.staging )select * FROM ( SELECT [ProjectWork Number], WeekValue, WeekNO From PivotData )A PIVOT (Sum(WeekValue) For WeekNO in ([Apr-03-2016], [Apr-10-2016])) As PivotResult;
```